# OpenCV changing matrix via submatrixes

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to change my matrix via sub-matrices step by step. But there is no change on the pixel values. Output pixel values are the same as input pixel values. Also my "wavenoise" function pretty working.

Here is my code:

```
cv::Mat wave_trans = Mat::zeros(nr, nc, CV_64FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
    Range Hhigh = Range(nc / 2, nc-1);
    Range Hlow = Range(0, nc / 2 - 1);
    Range Vhigh = Range(nr / 2, nr-1);
    Range Vlow = Range(0, nr / 2 - 1);


    Mat wave_trans_temp1 = Mat(wave_trans, Vlow, Hhigh);
    wave_trans_temp1 = wavenoise(wave_trans_temp1, NoiseVar);


    Mat wave_trans_temp2 = Mat(wave_trans, Vhigh, Hlow);
    wave_trans_temp2 = wavenoise(wave_trans_temp2, NoiseVar);


    Mat wave_trans_temp3 = Mat(wave_trans, Vhigh, Hhigh);
    wave_trans_temp3 = wavenoise(wave_trans_temp3, NoiseVar);

    nc = nc / 2;
    nr = nr / 2;
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your `wavenoise` function which reallocates the matrix (it would be useful to show it). You then assign the result, pointing the `wave_trans_temp*` variable to the new data. Instead, use `copyTo` on the result of the `wavenoise` function to copy the values into the submatrix. You need to keep in mind that `cv::Mat` behaves like a smart pointer -- assignment just changes what the object refers to, but doesn't cause a deep copy of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `cv::Mat`, it is important to keep in mind that it is a reference counted handle to the underlying data array.

As such, there are two (for our purpose) overloads of the assignment operator, which have significantly different behaviours.

The first one takes a matrix:

[`cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const cv::Mat& m)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302)

> Matrix assignment is an O(1) operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared and the reference counter, if any, is incremented.

And the second one takes a matrix expression:

[`cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const cv::MatExpr& expr)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2a0798475170fb3a23b5bc63686de334)

> As opposite to the first form of the assignment operation, the second form can reuse already allocated matrix if it has the right size and type to fit the matrix expression result.

Hence, an expression such as

```
nc = nc / 2;
```

will update the values of `nc`, since `nc / 2` is a `cv::MatExpr`.

However, when we assign a `cv::Mat`, such as one returned from some function

```
cv::Mat foo(cv::Mat m);

// ...
void baz(cv::Mat input) {
     cv::Mat bar(input);

     bar = foo(bar); // bar now points to whatever foo returned, input is not changed
}
```

---

To solve this problem, you can use [`cv::Mat::copyTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4331fa88593a9a9c14c0998574695ebb) to copy the result of your function into the submatrix/view.

For example

```
Mat wave_trans_temp3 = Mat(wave_trans, Vhigh, Hhigh);
wavenoise(wave_trans_temp3, NoiseVar).copyTo(wave_trans_temp3);
```